# Add event to Added dynamic DOM button - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I've read almost all of the available topic on this.
most of them repeat themselves with the "you should write .on('click' function(){}) and it fixes your problem.
So - I added dynamically button, and I've defined an event for this button.
what happens to me - click on the button -> redirect the page to the same URL with a question mark at the end -> localhost:3000/blabla/bla?
before the redirection, It changes the value and then removing the DOM container of the button and redirection
I've tried various definition position -
first in the document ready function,
then in the static wrapper ready
then in the static wrapper inside the ready document
and so on...
also, I've tried to make an outside function.

```
<script>
$(function(){

$('#new-order').on('click',function(e) {
$('#bottom').slideToggle(1000);
});

// btn-delete-item event

// btn-increase event

    $('#items').on('click','.btn-increase',function(){
    console.log("HEY")
    quantityLabel = $(this).parent().find('#line-item-quantity');
    addedQntty = parseInt(quantityLabel.text())+1;
    quantityLabel.text(addedQntty);
    console.log('added quantity')
});

// btn-decrease event

// btn-add-item event
$('.btn-add-item').on('click',function(){
    var prodID,quantity,html,itemID,itemTitle,itemPrice,itemDOM,prodPrice;
    prodID = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    itemTitle= $(this).parent().find('#title').text();
    quantity = $(this).parent().find('input').val();
    prodPrice= $(this).parent().find('#price').text();
    itemPrice = parseInt(quantity)*parseInt(prodPrice);
    itemDOM = $('#items').children();
    itemDOM.length>0 ? itemID=itemDOM.last().attr('id').slice(-1) : itemID = 0;
    html = `<div id="line-item-${itemID}">Title:<label id="line-item-name">${itemTitle}</label>Price:<label id="line-item-price">${itemPrice}</label>quantity<label id="line-item-quantity">${quantity}</label><button class="btn-decrease">-</button><button class="btn-increase">+</button><button class="btn-delete-item">delete</button></div>`;
    $('#items').append($(html));
});
});
</script>
```

Hope I made the question as clear as possible.

Comment: Use event.preventDefault() and event.stopPropagation() may help you

Comment: Your question is far from being clear. You need to add the relevant markup (HTML). If your button is inside a form element, clicking it will submit the form which will reload the page (uness form has an `action` param) and all your already bound events are gone. New ones will be bound on the new page. In order to prevent this, use `.preventDefault()` on either the button `click` event or on the form `submit` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default type of `<button>` is "submit"

So to use a button in a form for actions other than submit use

```
<button type="button">
```

It sounds like you are causing page to reload due to browser form submit

Comment: Amazing, thank you for your time. worked for me. It was part of a form and I now understand why this happend

Answer (score 0):

On the click function of add item button you're trying to append `$(html)`, just fix this one and try again, write it like that

```
$('#items').append(html);
```

you declared a variable "html" and in your code you're trying to append the whole html.
hope that fix it.